# Use current display scale in WPF ContextMenu

Tags: wpf

My WPF application is Per-Monitor Aware and normally scales well. But when the app window is on a second monitor with scale=150% and I open a context menu it uses scale=100% from the main display making menu items quite small:

[image]
(Interestingly the submenu items use correct 150% scale)

I open the context menu setting IsOpen = true:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

            menu.Items.Add("item 1");
            menu.Items.Add("item 2");

            MenuItem submenu = new MenuItem();
            submenu.Header = "submenu";
            submenu.Items.Add("more 1");
            submenu.Items.Add("more 2");
            menu.Items.Add(submenu);

            menu.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

How to configure context menu to use display settings it is opened on, not from the default main display?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Starting from 4.6.2 per monitor DPI aware is enabled by default, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865238/my-wpf-app-is-per-monitor-dpi-aware-out-of-the-box-i-was-not-expecting-that)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski My app is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I have .NET Framework 4.8 installed.

Comment: The Same Problem here. Did you found a solution/Workaround?

Comment: @gReX I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can RenderTransform to undo Scaling from PrimaryScreen and Scale to dpiScale from Visual:

```
var visual = e.Source as Visual;
if (visual != null)
{
     var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(visual);
     System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.
           GetDpi(DpiType.Effective, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY);
     menu.RenderTransform = 
          new ScaleTransform(dpiScale.DpiScaleX / ((double)dpiX / 96), 
                            dpiScale.DpiScaleY / ((double)dpiY / 96));
     menu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still have this problem, Here is a  solution:
Set contextmenu's `PlacementTarget` to the parent control who has correct dpi scale.

Source <sup><sub>(no affiliation)</sub></sup>: https://blog.lindexi.com/post/WPF-%E4%BF%AE%E5%A4%8D-ContextMenu-%E5%9C%A8%E5%BC%80%E5%90%AF-PerMonitorV2-%E5%90%8E%E6%89%80%E7%94%A8-DPI-%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF.html