# Prevent blurriness when dpi changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

When a user changes the system dpi (in Settings -> Display) a WPF Window becomes blurry. Closing the application and restarting it makes it clear again.

How can I get the Window clear again **without** closing it?

Recreate by creating a WPF app, adding a button and running it. Then change the dpi as mentioned above. Even changing it back again doesn't help.

Comment: happens for every wpf application(even newly created ones)?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes. Just create one, put a button on it, and change the system dpi. You'll see the text on the button become blurry.

Comment: i'm not very familiar with dpi. is there such setting? is it equal to the 'resolution(1920*1080)' list?

Comment: As a workaround you can monitor for DPI change and force UI reloading. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64355684/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr DpiChanged doesn't fire. Try it and see for yourself. Also, how would I be able to reload the UI - do you mean remove all elements from the Window and put them back there? Because if so, it doesn't work - the button returns blurry.

Comment: To reload UI try to close window and open it again. You need to customize [entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6156550/1997232). If reloading UI is not enough, then just do [restart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4773632/1997232). User don't change DPI often, right?

Comment: @Sinatr `User don't change DPI often, right?` - _Some_ user is going to... I was hoping there would be some method I can call to "reload" the dpi.

Comment: Have you tried registering to SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged in your MainWindow.xaml.cs, and then calling `this.UpdateLayout()`?

Comment: @TamBui `UpdateLayout` doesn't help. Tested.

Comment: @Sinatr I have a PC with displays with different DPIs, whenever I drag a window from one screen to another that counts as a _DPI change_ as far as the application is concerned. That said, **just enable per-monitor DPI awareness** and WPF should handle it fine.

Comment: @Dai, I expect wpf applications to be dpi aware [by defaut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35865238/1997232). But it seems to be not ideal. Perhaps OP should post [mcve] so that you can reproduce the issue and try to find a better solution. I just suggest a workaround - to restart, that should help if everything was ok before DPI change.

Comment: @Sinatr I’m guessing the OP’s project is an older WPF app running against something older than .NET Fx 4.7.2 and so per-monitor DPI awareness is disabled for back-compact purposes. The OP needs to test a _brand new_ blank WPF project targeting .NET Fx 4.8 or .NET 5.

Comment: @Sinatr `minimal reproducible example` - I'm pretty sure anyone who's capable of answering this question is also capable of creating a WPF application and adding a button to it.

Comment: @Dai No. It's a the latest .net 4.8 with the latest Visual Studio version. With a brand new WPF project. Try it and see.

Comment: @ispiro “ I'm pretty sure anyone who's capable of answering this question is also capable of creating a WPF application and adding a button to it” - yes, and per-monitor DPI awareness works correctly for me. Something is wrong or broken with your computer.

Comment: @Dai But your suggestion for per-monitor dpi awareness did work. Which I find strange since I'm only working on one monitor. Anyway, you can post that as an answer, because strange or not - it works.

Comment: @Dai See my previous comment. Per-monitor DPI awareness does, in fact, work. Thanks!

Comment: @ispiro How, **exactly** did you enable per-monitor DPI awareness?

Comment: @Dai I said it _did_ work. Not that it didn't. And I used `<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>`.

Comment: @ispiro You shouldn’t need to do that though. Unless, did your project already have a custom app.manifest?

Comment: @Dai As I've said above, this is a completely new WPF project. VS -> New project -> etc. so yes, I needed to add an app.manifest file to it. And if you think per-monitor-etc. is by default - [you're not alone. And you are backed by a Microsoft blog post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218709/939213) But unfortunately  [still wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217355/wpf-application-blurry-on-high-dpi-screen-on-windows-10#comment85923370_39218709).

Comment: @Dai Please feel free to post your answer. My answer is just there in case you don't.

Comment: @Dai Also, instead of me posting an answer myself, please feel free to post an answer to [my bountied question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68379924/939213) since you're the one who deserves that bounty.

Comment: @ispiro I really don't need +50 reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) pointed out, adding per-monitor dpi-awareness fixes the issue.

Why, I'm not sure, since that's not supposed to affect a device using one monitor. But it works.

Since it seems that [many think that per-monitor dpi-awareness is on by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218709/939213), let me point out, [as pointed out by Ben Voit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627367/why-is-systemevents-displaysettingschanged-raised-when-switching-user/68627572?noredirect=1#comment121284473_68627572), that [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217355/wpf-application-blurry-on-high-dpi-screen-on-windows-10/39218709#comment85923370_39218709).