# How can I reset VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi() to return the true DPI?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

In WPF applications `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi()` gets the dpi when the application is launched. Subsequent calls return the same value even if the user has meanwhile changed the dpi in Settings -> Display.

How can I "reset" the dpi that `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi()` sees ***without** restarting the application*?

Some code:

```
Title = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX.ToString();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918890/6734762

Comment: You can try to look [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/VisualTreeHelper.cs,108) what it does.

Comment: @mm8 Not for a particular screen. And the Visual I feed it is either the Window itself (`this`) or a `Button` on it. Both fail to get updated.

Comment: @ispiro: How do I reproduce your issue, step by step from scratch?

Comment: @mm8 You create a WPF app, add a button that sets the Title to `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX.ToString()`, run app, change dpi in Settings, and click the button. You have enough rep, though, that I assume you knew that.

Comment: Did you try the native `GetDpiForWindow` API?

Comment: Have you set dpiAwareness in app.manifest?

Comment: The dpi landscape has evolved over years and WPF is somehow stuck in the passed. I wrote a bunch of DPI tools here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888078/403671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding per-monitor dpi-awareness fixes blurriness. It also fixes this. Why, I'm not sure, since this problem exists even when a single monitor is used. But it works.

You will need to add an app.manifest file for that.